# use-package - :init or :config

Tags: use-package

Is there any rule by which the user can determine whether the package configuration requires `:init` or `:config`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is there any rule by which the user can determine whether the package configuration requires `:init` or `:config`?

There is no general rule which applies to all settings and packages; you just need to familiarise yourself with the meaning of these keywords by reading the [README file](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/README.md) of `use-package`.

In summary, the `:init` block is run at startup, as if you had placed its constituent forms at the top-level (i.e. outside of a typical call to `use-package`) of your `user-init-file`. This means they are always run, regardless of whether the corresponding package has been loaded or not.

The `:config` block, on the other hand, is run after the corresponding package has been loaded, by way of the [`eval-after-load`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html) mechanism.

As such, you can improve your startup time by moving applicable long-running settings from `:init` to `:config`. If you need to modify a variable which is only defined after loading a particular package, you similarly need to place this in the `:config` block. Some variables, such as `gnus-home-directory`, need to be set before their corresponding package is loaded, so they should be placed in `:init`. I strongly advise putting all applicable `add-hook`/`remove-hook` calls in the `:init` block, as hooks can be modified even when unbound, and this affords more modularity to your setup.

You can often avoid having to figure out where to place a particular setting by using the new `:custom` keyword, or by using the [Easy Customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) interface directly.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but use-package is a famous package and i really have a problem understanding this. C-h f use-package tells me :init code is run *before* package has been loaded, but the github page of vertico (famous emacs package) tells to run (vertico-mode) in :init and it works? How can (vertico-mode) be successfully evaluated if the package is not yet loaded???

Comment: @Matthias That's because `vertico-mode` is probably autoloaded, i.e. Emacs knows where to find it when it is called.  See the section on autoloading in [`(info "(emacs) Lisp
Libraries")`](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Libraries.html#index-autoload).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there is a general rule (apart from "use `:init` for preconfiguration before actual package loading and use `:config` for other, well, configuration").

But I for myself use `:init` when, for example, I want to add some other mode map keybindings to use functions from "this" package. And still want "this" package to be lazy loaded.

Here is the example of lazy loading of `dired-ranger`:

```el
(use-package dired-ranger
  :commands (dired-ranger-copy dired-ranger-paste dired-ranger-move)
  :init
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "M-w") 'dired-ranger-copy)
              (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-y") 'dired-ranger-paste)
              (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-y") 'dired-ranger-move))))
```

P.S.:
If there is no `:defer`, `:commands`, `:mode` and others that makes package loading lazy, then `:init` and `:config` should be more or less the same (but `:init` will be evaluated earlier :) )

Comment: Modifying key bindings in a mode hook means they are run **every time** you open a buffer in that mode. You only need to modify key bindings once, after the package is loaded. You can use the `:bind` keyword for this, or modify the key bindings in the `:config` block.

Comment: Indeed, never thought about it. But `:config` is too late -- lazy loading will not apply my bindings. And `:bind` with `:map` doesn't actually bind it.

Comment: `:config` is not too late - that's exactly when `dired-mode-map` is first defined. You're probably just putting it in the wrong `use-package` form of `dired-ranger` instead of `dired`, where `dired-mode-map` is defined. This might also explain why your `:bind` does not work. Basically, either you are doing something wrong or `use-package` has a bug. Do not confuse local keybindings and `eval-after-load` with global keybindings of autoloaded commands/keymaps.

Comment: @Basil, thx, you're right. My problem was that I have set `use-package-always-ensure` and when I try to use-package dired it fails to fetch it from elpa. But having `:ensure nil` there solves the problem and I can set up chained package loading `dired` -> `dired-ranger` using `:after`.